# apache htaccess rewrite url for seo friendliness

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying and failing at the moment to rewrite my urls for seo friendliness. Can you point out where I might be going wrong?

I'm trying to rewrite this url:

```
http://www.chillisource.co.uk/product?&cat=Grocery&q=Daves%20Gourmet&page=1&prod=B0000DID5R&prodName=Daves_Insanity_Sauce
```

To this:

```
http://www.chillisource.co.uk/product/Grocery/Daves%20Gourmet/1/B0000DID5R/Daves_Insanity_Sauce
```

This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+) /product?&cat=$1&q=$2&page=$3&prod=$4&prodName=$5
```

The first part allows me to go without the .php in the filenane.

This currently gives me error 500 when I try and go to: http://www.chillisource.co.uk/product/Grocery/Daves%20Gourmet/1/B0000DID5R/Daves_Insanity_Sauce

I've read up on mod_rewrite but I'm a novice programmer and finding it hard going. I don't get how $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 which are the variables in my url get transfered to the other side, is ([a-zA-Z0-9]+) correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For future use you might look at the following site. Some really nice already working rewrite code: http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php?page=all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1 corresponds to your first set of parenthesis in the first part of your rewrite rule. $2 to the second set of parenthesis and so on.

`Daves%20Gourmet` contains a space character which is not accounted for in your 2nd pattern i.e. things between 2nd set of parenthesis. Again you are not taking care of `_` in the url.

I would try this

```
RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z]+)/([\sa-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+) /product?&cat=$1&q=$2&page=$3&prod=$4&prodName=$5
```

Assuming your page parameter is always an integer and your 4th parameter contains only upper case letters.