# How can I rewrite any .htms in a directory to pass their names as an argument to a PHP file?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a bunch of pages that need static URL paths, for example:

```
foo/bar/fooey/qwertyuiop.htm
```

However, these pages don't exist. They are all the same except with slightly different variables.

So I created `/foo/bar/details.php`, which takes the parameters "id" and "type".

Any ideas how I can make a Rewrite rule that redirects all .htms in /foo and it's subdirectories to details.php, like this:

```
/foo/bar/fooey/abc123.htm     --> /foo/bar/details.php?id=abc123

/foo/bar/xyzzy/hellothere.htm --> /foo/bar/details.php?id=hellothere
```

and

```
/foo/bar/applepie/check_pie_status.htm?type=peach
```

would be rewritten to

```
/foo/bar/details.php?id=check_pie_status&type=peach
```

In other words, any requested .htm would be rewritten to that PHP file, without the client seeing it.

Comment: I have the strangest code questions...

Comment: possible duplicate of [apache htaccess rewrite url for seo friendliness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053067/apache-htaccess-rewrite-url-for-seo-friendliness)

Comment: @MarcB This is different, as all .htms in (and only in) the directory (and subdirectories of) /foo/bar are rewritten, where the page you linked has to do with passing the directory names of each subdirectory to a new URL parameter.

Comment: I agree that this question is *different* from the linked question.

Comment: @anubhava It seems to have been flagged as a duplicate or an answer...  How can I fix that? (Or see who flagged it to ask them)

Comment: @AustinBurk: You need not worry about single duplicate vote. It needs 5 votes to mark it duplicate. Your question is not a duplicate so there won't be 5 votes there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in the `/foo/bar/` folder's htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]+/|)([^/.]+)\.htm$ details.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ details.php?id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]+/[^/]+)/.*?/([^/.]+)\.htm$ $1/details.php?id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

its sounds like a landing page issue..

from my experience i can offer those ideas:

1. create a different folder path using Nginx sites-enable folder at /etc/site-enable.
   this will allow to attach a certain domain to a folders path or to create a general rule that will send any /foo to a certein path.
2. create script that loads a specific folder for every domain. i think that a DB using domain as a key with a path txt is the best solution.. this is a bit of system design issue.
3. calling to the path using Reg-ex at your main index php file extracting this data from $_SERVER URI..